# Open a link on select using react starter kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, react-starter-kit

I am pretty new to Java script and this could be a really simple answer.

I am using react-starter-kit along with react-select.
On a select, a particular function is executed.
From within this function, I want the app to navigate to another route (open another url).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Show us some code? What did you try?

Comment: You can follow any example according to your React version [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Comment: @AnujDhanju react-starter-kit uses universal-router, so those answers may not apply.

Comment: @Boky I am actually pretty lost in terms of how to navigate out. So there is no code to show actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I managed to solve this by myself, by following this [link](https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router/issues/72)

react-starter-kit uses the universal router which handles the routing part of the starter kit. The navigation part is handled by the history module.

To navigate to another part of the app, I just had to import history and then push in the path, like below:

```
import history from '../../core/history';                
history.push(newpath);
```